# select last elements from parents

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to JQuery so this is probably an easy one...

Consider this HTML structure - I know it is not valid HTML but that's not the point:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Basically I need to select the last table cell from each table row where the checkbox is marked, in this case the table cells containing "1.3" and "2.3" (not "3.3"). Finding the checked checkboxes is easy but somehow I always end up with only the last table cell ("2.3") from the last table row. Does someone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var foo = $('#mytable tr:has("input:checked") td:last-child');
```

Comment: Nice solution, I'll go with this one even though the other suggestions are valid as well. I guess the performance is a little better when using CSS selectors?

Comment: As for performance, I really can't tell without running a perf test on it (sometimes the CSS selectors are faster, sometimes the methods are), but two things this has going for it is (1) readability (heck, that's one line of code!), and (2) it uses `:has()`, which is the selector designed for your specific use case (i.e. an `element` that contains `element`). Quite underused, actually. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var result;

$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input').attr('checked') == 'checked') {           
        result = $(this).children('td:last-child').html();
        alert(result);
    }       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an easier way to do this but this is my solution:

```
$("#mytable td input:checked")
    .parent().parent()
    .find("td:last")
    .css("color","red");​
```

To see a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/exQZJ/

Comment: `$("#mytable td input:checked").closest('tr').find('td:last').css({color:"red"});` Nowadays we use `.closest()` instead of `.parent().parent().parent().parent()`  http://jsbin.com/oduguk/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the jsfiddle example JAstanton! It turned out to be very close to my original attempt, except for the .find which did the trick